# asp.net core authentication with .Map()

Tags: c#, authentication, asp.net-core

i'm trying to use hmac authentication on specific api controllers which starts with `/api/ext` so i added these configuration on startup class

```
app.Map("/api/ext", builder =>
            {
                builder.UseHmacAuthentication(new HmacAuthenticationOptions
                {
                    SecretKey = "abc670d15a584f4baf0ba48455d3b155",
                    AppId = "jDEf7bMcJVFnqrPd599aSIbhC0IasxLBpGAJeW3Fzh4=",
                    AutomaticAuthenticate = true
                });
                builder.UseMvc();
            });
```

but when i send the request i'm getting 404 not found error but when i remove above code it hits the controller action. am i missing something?

**UPDATE**

finally i came up with this

```
bool IsApiRequest(HttpContext context) => context.Request.Path.ToString().StartsWith("/api/ext/");
            app.UseWhen(IsApiRequest, builder =>
            {
                builder.UseHmacAuthentication(new HmacAuthenticationOptions
                {
                    SecretKey = "abc670d15a584f4baf0ba48455d3b155",
                    AppId = "jDEf7bMcJVFnqrPd599aSIbhC0IasxLBpGAJeW3Fzh4=",
                    AutomaticAuthenticate = true
                });
             builder.UseMvc();
            });
```

seems it works now (validate properly and hit controller action)

then on controller action `public async Task<IActionResult> Test([FromBody] ApiIdentityUser model)` model gets null but when i remove middleware authentication gets values..
any thought?

**UPDATE 2**

so i here is my another alternation and found something interesting i added auth module as middleware like this

```
app.UseMiddleware<HmacAuthenticationMiddleware>(Options.Create(new 
    HmacAuthenticationOptions
                {
                    SecretKey = "abc670d15a584f4baf0ba48455d3b155",
                    AppId = "jDEf7bMcJVFnqrPd599aSIbhC0IasxLBpGAJeW3Fzh4=",
                    AutomaticAuthenticate = false,
                    AutomaticChallenge = false
                }));
```

still i got the error then i removed

```
Options.Create(new HmacAuthenticationOptions
            {
                SecretKey = "abc670d15a584f4baf0ba48455d3b155",
                AppId = "jDEf7bMcJVFnqrPd599aSIbhC0IasxLBpGAJeW3Fzh4=",
                AutomaticAuthenticate = false,
                AutomaticChallenge = false
            })
```

from above code and set keys at the implementation level then it worked but why?

Comment: Are you calling `app.UseIdentity()`?

Comment: @OzgurGUL yes im calling `app.UseIdentity()` before use `app.Map("/api/ext")`

Answer (score 1):

Using `app.UseIdentity()` will add `CookieAuthentication` to your application and all unauthenticated requests will redirect to
`/Account/Login` by default.

So, if you are not using `CookieAuthentication`, try removing `app.UseIdentity()`.

Comment: my problem is why model not getting bind.. authorization work properly. only `[frombody ]` getting null

Answer (score 0):

Its looks like you have forgotten to use
    `builder.UseMvc();`
Since API is mvc Based its not binding models.